# What if selector return null when executing $('.myclass').show() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If jQuery selector return no element, then what will happen. For example, I execute the following:

```
$('.myclass').show();
```

Based on my test, it seems jQuery will check whether $('.myclass') is null, if not, then it will execute .show(), otherwise, nothing happens.

I translate the above codeline to JavaScript, as below:

```
document.querySelector('.myclass').style.display = 'block';
```

But this time if document.querySelector('.myclass') return null, there will be an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no matching elements, it does nothing.

If there are any matching elements, it will show all such matching elements.

It's somewhat similar to the following:

```
for (const elm of document.querySelectorAll(selector)) {
  elm.style.display = 'block';
}
```

If there are no elements matching whatever `selector` is, nothing happens, but no error is thrown.

Similarly, if there are no elements matching `.myclass`, no iteration happens, and nothing changes in the DOM, and no error is thrown.

Comment: Thank you. I just translate the code to JavaScript, and it seems that if document.querySelector('.myclass') returns null, there will be error with document.querySelector('.myclass').style.display = 'block';

Comment: If you do `querySelector`, you'll get a single element. The code in my answer uses `querySelectorAll`, which returns an array-like collection - similarly, jQuery's `$` retrieves an array-like collection, which `.show` then iterates over. There's no error when iterating over an empty collection in either vanilla JS nor in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use document.querySelectorAll('.myclass').style.display = 'block'; directly?

Comment: No, because `querySelectorAll` returns a collection, not a single element. You'll have to iterate over the collection.